# Поиск шаблона среди строк

Tags: алгоритм, строки, шаблоны, производительность

У меня есть огромное число строк, и я знаю, что они построены по ограниченному набору шаблонов, но мне неизвестно каких. Мне нужно вычислить эти шаблоны **довольно быстро при очень большом наборе данных**.

Например, такому набору шаблонов (неизвестному мне):

```
"Hello, my {0} is: {1}"  
"{0} has left our team."  
"{0} has joined the team {1}!"
```

Соответствует набор строк ниже, только которые есть у меня:

```
Hello, my name is: Slim Shady  
Mike has left our team.  
Mike has joined the team Liquid!  
Hello, my name is Nikole  
Nick has joined the team Spirit!  
Elizabeth has left our team.
```

Задача: найти шаблоны по подобным строкам. То есть, найти закономерности в тексте, которые позволяют придумать такие шаблоны автоматически. Строк может быть очень много.

Я пока придумал использовать что-то вроде редакционного расстояния с помощью N-грамм.

Но у этой штуки более широкая область применения, чем мне нужно, а время работы не менее важно, чем точность нахождения шаблонов.

Так как у меня есть слова, которые будут совпадать полностью и без ошибок, и мне кажется, что тут можно как-то повысить быстродействие за счёт этого.

Я подумал над составлением алфавита из слов, а не букв, чтобы поиск по предложениям шёл по словам.

**UPD**: На всякий случай уточню, что на момент компиляции нет ни шаблонов, ни самих строк. Строки подаются программе на вход, а шаблоны никто нам не даст.

**UPD2**: Нужно в реальном времени находить шаблоны в уже пройденных строках так, чтобы в последующих мы могли находить их соответствие.

> (Комментарий) Предположим, у нас есть `n` предложений `Мама наша мыла раму` и `m` предложений `Мама мыла мою раму`. Это должен быть один шаблон `Мама {0} мыла {1} раму` или два шаблона: `Мама {0} мыла раму`, `Мама мыла {0} раму`? Таких примеров можно придумать крайне много. Для того, чтобы избегать таких неоднозначностей, нужно либо дательнее понять, что за задача перед Вами, либо же, нужно Вам указать конкретный смысл, чтобы можно было найти единственное решение.

Шаблон должен быть как можно более общим из возможных, т.е. `Мама {0} мыла {1} раму`. Но именно для похожих строк. А не один шаблон `{0}`

> (Комментарий) Возникает вопрос, почему не использовать шаблон `{0}`? Он -- максимально общий. Кажется, проблема в том, что над множеством шаблонов нужно ввести какой-то порядок. В общем случае, этот порядок нелинеен. Его нужно как-то линеаризовать. Это кажется сложной задачей. Если Вы скажете, зачем эта задача Вам нужна, можно на эту тему подумать.

В этом и заключается вся задача :D Мне нужно находить шаблоны этих строк, так чтобы в шаблоны объединялись сильно схожие строки, можно, например, взять что-то вроде процента схожести в виде критения.

**UPD3**: Шаблон должен объединить похожие строки. Похожими строками будем считать строки, которые совпадают на `N%`.

Comment: Все зависит от конкретной задачи. Насколько быстро нужно? Для обработки сообщений чата в реальном времени подошли бы и регулярные выражения.

Comment: Нет, регулярки точно не подойдут по скорости, нужно обрабатывать миллионы строк и довольно быстро и я не уверен, что они тут вообще помогут, шаблон то неизвестен.

Comment: А если использовать редакционное расстояние, но не в буквах, а в словах? Т.е. если предложения отличаются на одно слово, то расстояние равно 1.

Comment: @insolor , Я вот об этом и думал, но мне же нужно найти в итоге этот шаблон. Искать для этого редакционное предписание кажется мне слишком тяжеловесным для такого, можно конечно найти расстояние, а потом закостылить поиск, но я больше чем уверен, что есть (можно придумать) алгоритм эффективнее

Comment: В каком виде должны быть обнаружены шаблоны?

Comment: Очевидно, что коль скоро у Вас нет шаблонов, существует очень много решений. Нужно уточнение от Вас, в каком смысле искать решние?

Comment: @hedgehogues, добавил уточнение, но вроде как по примеру должно быть понятно, что я хочу найти шаблоны строк, по которым они составлены.

Comment: Вы не поняли. Предположим, у нас есть `n` предложений `Мама наша мыла раму` и `m` предложений `Мама мыла мою раму`. Это должен быть один шаблон `Мама {0} мыла {1} раму` или два шаблона: `Мама {0} мыла раму`, `Мама мыла {0} раму`? Таких примеров можно придумать крайне много. Для того, чтобы избегать таких неоднозначностей, нужно либо дательнее понять, что за задача перед Вами, либо же, нужно Вам указать конкретный смысл, чтобы можно было найти единственное решение.

Comment: @hedgehogues, и правда не понял. Шаблон должен быть как можно более общим из возможных, т.е. `Мама {0} мыла {1} раму`. Но именно для похожих строк. А не один шаблон `{0}` :D

Comment: В таком случае, возникает вопрос, почему не использовать шаблон `{0}`? Он -- максимально общий. Кажется, проблема в том, что над множеством шаблонов нужно ввести какой-то порядок. В общем случае, этот порядок нелинеен. Его нужно как-то линеаризовать. Это кажется сложной задачей. Если Вы скажете, зачем эта задача Вам нужна, можно на эту тему подумать.

Comment: @hedgehogues, в этом и заключается вся задача :D Мне нужно находить шаблоны этих строк, так чтобы в шаблоны объединялись сильно схожие строки.

Comment: Есть два крайних случая покрытия шаблонами Вашего множества строк - это шаблон {0} и множество шаблонов совпадающие с множеством входных строк. Вы ничего не сказали о требованиях к этим покрытиям. Пока нет достаточных данных, чтобы начинать думать о Ваше проблеме.

Comment: А если алгоритмами поиска похожести строк пройтись? Ну т.е через LCS алгоритм, вы удостоверяетесь, что эта строка на 80% похожа на строку, которую вы ранее видели, а потом пытаетесь вычленить из нее расхождения.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов, я вроде в комментах выше уже указал, сейчас ещё в  вопрос добавлю

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если количество шаблонов ограничено, и они довольно равномерно распределены в данных, то смысла в **очень** большом наборе данных нет. Вы можете добыть шаблоны и из набора данных поменьше.

Решение "в лоб" представляется таким:

Можно придумать некоторую функцию получающую слова из строк (например просто разбить по пробелам и вырезать знаки препинания).

Затем, составить частотный словарь. Например слово 'Hello' встречается дважды в наборе из примера. Кроме того, можно ещё посчитать количество вхождений слова в определённой позиции, чтобы смотреть потом не просто частоту слова, а частоту слова где-то в районе 3-5 позиции, например.

Теперь для любого слова можно сделать предположение о том, является оно частью шаблона или нет. Если слово достаточно часто встречается где-то в районе текущей позиции, то скорее всего оно часть шаблона.

Для каждой строки из набора данных строим шаблон и оставляем только уникальные значения.

В этом случае данные придётся обработать дважды (первый раз строя частотный словарь, второй -- шаблоны), потому что нам сперва нужна информация о том, что из себя представляет весь набор.

Нейронка может помочь подобрать пороговые значения и получить лучшие результаты.

Comment: Это прикольный вариант и я уверен, что рабочий, но дважды пройти по данным в моём случае не выйдет :с

Comment: а суть большого набора данных не в том, чтобы найти шаблоны, а он просто есть и какой-то шаблон может встретиться только в последней сотне из 100 000 строк. Ну это я так :с

Answer (score 2):

На первом шаге алгоритма у вас вся первая строка "ABC" порежется на слова, и эти слова расставятся по дереву (в линейном порядке A->B->C)

Получив на вход аналогичую ("AEC") строку, вы нарисуете еще один путь в дереве, просто в одном из уровней у вас появится ответвление, которое потом сойдется обратно:

```
  ->B->
A       C
  ->E->
```

Таким образом, каждая ваша строка - это просто путь по этому дереву.

Набрав для какого-то узла достаточно выходящих веток, которые потом сходятся обратно, можно сделать вывод, что на этом месте стоит произвольный параметр.

Comment: Перечитайте, пожалуйста, вопрос. У меня нет шаблонов на момент компиляции, как и самих строк.

Comment: Таскайте с собой gcc, в чем проблема?

Comment: А как вы предлагаете построить сами регулярки?)

Comment: Шаблоны же вам в каком-то виде дадут? Так и пусть дают в виде регулярок.

Comment: У меня НЕТ И НЕ БУДЕТ ШАБЛОНОВ. Вопрос как раз и заключается в том как эти шаблоны вычислить, а не как найти строки по шаблонам ._.

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: Этот вариант я уже рассматривал и специально в примерах добавил строки, где начало идёт с параметра. Как раз в таких случаях этот вариант не прокатит точно, но есть и другие нерабочие кейсы.

Comment: Добавьте в начало каждой строки фиктивный токен, и все вернется на круги своя.

Comment: но это не решит остальные кейсы, такие как, например, разное количество слов в параметре

Comment: Ну будет у вас получатся ответвление не длины 1, а произвольной, которое все равно будет приходить в тот же узел. Быстрее уже пример запрограммировать, чем спорить с вами.

Comment: Но как вы будете определять следующий элемент в таком варианте? буду рад увидеть примерчик :3

Comment: Очень хороший вариант! С год назад решил так аналогичную проблему)

Comment: @Kir_Antpov, но он ведь не решает данную проблему :с

Answer (score 1):

возможно вы хотите слепить какую нибудь "нейронку"?
На самом деле ваш вопрос требует большей конкретики (и понимания того , на каком уровне ваш математический аппарат?). Ваша задача найдет исчерпывающее решение в одном из разделов **машинного обучения - "Обучение с учителем"** !!!
Для выявления закономерностей и "шаблонов", обратите внимание на алгоритм **CAEP** (Classification by Aggregating Emerging Patterns)...
P.S. Всего наилучшего, "удав" в помощь!!!

Comment: Идея прикольная, спасибо, но не думаю, что мне подойдёт ML :c Тут скорее попытки придумать алгоритм

Answer (score 0):

Для начала вооружаемся алгоритмом поиска % совпадения между строками.

Создаем БД из 2 ух таблиц:

Patterns- где будут храниться шаблоны
Queue- где будут храниться необработанные сообщения.

Далее алгоритм такой:

Добавляем сообщение в Queue и проверяем Patterns через алгоритм частичного поиска. Если % нас удволитворяет, то говорим, что шаблон был найден и удаляем запись из Queue.

Если не нашли, то сравниваем запись с каждой записью из Queue через частичное сравнение.

Когда нашли наиболее похожий вариант, то начинаем обрезать все лишнее, формируя шаблон.

Не знаю, как у него с быстродействием будет, но можно использовать всякие хитрости, например не имеет смысла сопоставлять слишком короткую строку со слишком длинной и т д.

Comment: Это то очевидно, суть вопроса не в этом, а в том как сделать вот эту часть => `начинаем обрезать все лишнее, формируя шаблон`

Comment: @Kamushek перебором. Берешь букву первого слова, сверяешь с первой буквой второго слова. Совпало? Берешь вторую букву и так далее, пока не найдутся различия. Ты нашел левую часть шаблона. Далее идешь область второго совпадения и находишь середину и так далее. Тут важно заложить эвристику, так как строки могут быть разной длинны => нужно при встречи пунктуации или пробелов перепроверки делать.

Comment: Увы, но такое не прокатит. У нас может быть параметр в самом начале, параметры могут состоять из разного количества слов, в параметрах могут быть знаки препинания :с

Answer (score 0):

1. Справочник незначащих слов NSLOVA (забивается вручную) [{"наша"},{"мою"}], заполняется путем разбора вручную первых 50 предложений. (и т.д.)
2. Справочник обращений OBRASCHENIYA [{"мама"}], заполняется путем разбора вручную первых 50 предложений. (и т.д.)
3. Алгоритм заменяет вместо найденных незначащих слов выставляет теги .
4. Алгоритм заменяет вместо найденных обращений выставляет теги  получаем шаблон.
5. Получившиеся выражение с тегами  и  это и есть шаблон.
   а) в шаблоне теги заменяются на пустые строки и пробелы заменяются на пустые строки получается "чистый шаблон" ("chistiy_shablon")
   б) в шаблоне теги заменяются на пустые строки и регулярным выражением собирается массив "шаблонных слов", которые сливаются в одну строку через запятую получается поле "shablonnie_slova".
6. В справочнике шаблонов добавляется шаблон [{"shablon":"  мыла  раму","chistiy_shablon":"мылараму"},"shablonnie_slova":"мыла,раму", "kolvoprimenenii":"1"].

На этом начальное заполнение справочников закончено.

Идет запуск основного алгоритма:
Получаем дату запуска алгоритма "vremyazapuska".
В цикле считывается строка. 
Из строки попытка сформировать шаблон (пункты 3,4) и чистый шаблон (5).
    Если шаблон равен входной строке(и строки нет в справочнике Исключений) - строка попадает в Справочник безшаблонных строк и 
    добавляется поле "vremyazapuska". Идет переход на следующую итерацию обработка 
    следующей строки.

```
Если нет попытка найти по полю "чистый шаблон" шаблон в справочнике шаблонов.
     Если не найден "чистый шаблон" шаблон добавляется в справочник шаблонов (пункт 
     6). Идет переход на следующую итерацию обработка следующей строки.

     Если найден "чистый шаблон" в справочнике шаблонов, то сравниваются поля с 
     текущим объектом шаблона и записью из базы (за исключением поля 
     "kolvoprimenenii").
            Если объекты равны - поле kolvoprimenenii увеличивается на 1.
            Если объекты разные по полю шаблон, то шаблон формируется с наибольшим 
            количеством тегов и записывается в базу. Поле kolvoprimenenii также в 
            этом случае увеличивается на 1.
```

Обработанная строка удаляется из лога.
Запускается проверка на количество безшаблонных строк. Если оно больше 50 - идет выход из программы.

Таблица бесшаблонных строк разбирается вручную или вспомогательным алгоритмом(собираются новые незначимые слова или обращения, если есть необходимость добавляется новый шаблон в справочник шаблонов). Если ничего со строкой сделать нельзя (нет ни незначащих слов и обращений ) - добавляется в Справочник Исключений. После этого строка удаляется из таблицы бесшаблонных строк.

После того как таблица бесшаблонных строк оказалась пуста, запускается основной алгоритм разбора строк.